# Docker failing to start in Debian 8 (status=1/FAILURE)

Tags: docker, systemd, debian-jessie

i have a Linux Server that's running Debian 8 Jessie and i'm trying to install Docker following this [gist](https://gist.github.com/frgomes/a6f889583860f5b330c06c8b46fa0f42) on Github.

I'm getting the following error returned anytime i try to start the Docker service:

```
admin@srvr1:~$ sudo systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Thu 2017-07-06 16:09:08 EDT; 47s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 32666 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 32666 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 06 16:09:08 yjuoy5v1ka systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 06 16:09:08 yjuoy5v1ka systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
Jul 06 16:09:08 yjuoy5v1ka systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Jul 06 16:09:08 yjuoy5v1ka systemd[1]: docker.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Jul 06 16:09:08 yjuoy5v1ka systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Jul 06 16:09:08 yjuoy5v1ka systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Jul 06 16:09:42 yjuoy5v1ka systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Jul 06 16:09:42 yjuoy5v1ka systemd[1]: docker.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Jul 06 16:09:42 yjuoy5v1ka systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Jul 06 16:09:45 yjuoy5v1ka systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Jul 06 16:09:45 yjuoy5v1ka systemd[1]: docker.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Jul 06 16:09:45 yjuoy5v1ka systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Jul 06 16:09:49 yjuoy5v1ka systemd[1]: Unit docker.service cannot be reloaded because it is inactive.
```

And that's all it says i can't identify anything that's a usual dead giveaway there, i'm running Nginx on port 80, i've installed PHP7.1 and MariaDB, i've removed Apache and besides that, so far, the server is pretty much stock so i don't know what might be causing this...

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced a similar error (but in Ubuntu 16.04). Try this:

**OPTION 1:**

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

Change the line

> ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://

to:

> ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -s overlay

or to:

> ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -s aufs

Save the file and run the next two commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Check after that if your docker runs, remember you will NOT see any images or containers after this, your previous ones are stored in "/var/lib/docker/overlay2".

**OPTION 2**

Other option is to move your containers to a backup folder and try to start a clean docker.service with overlay2, for this try the following:

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo mv /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker.bak
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

Change the line

> ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://

to:

> ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -s overlay2

Save the file and run the next commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start docker
```

After this second option, did it start okay? Remember that with this latter option your containers are in the "docker.bak" folder so `docker ps` won't show any container neither image.

I think is related to some problem in the containers and/or images stored with the overlay2 driver.

I have experienced this with Docker 17.12 and 18.03 on Ubuntu 16.04, on overlay2 over ext4. My Docker setup was running okay, started to crash out of the blue (and after several updates). I can show which updates were installed if someone wants to know).